# Excel VBA TextBox Events

Tags: vba, excel

Would like to ask expert here, why the below code doesn't work in excel sheet ? Basically this code will perform validation on input that user enter into BDTextBox, if format doesn't valid it will pop up a warning message. I've tested this code in excel sheet form and it works well however if change the textbox from form to embedded in excel sheet, it doesn't work.. any idea ?

```
Private Sub BDTextBox_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
If BDTextBox.Text <> "" Then
    If IsDate(BDTextBox.Text) Then
        BDTextBox.Text = Format(BDTextBox.Text, "yyyymmdd")
        FinalBusinessDate = BDTextBox.Text
    Else
        MsgBox "Please enter a valid date!" & vbNewLine & "Date format could be one of the following" & vbNewLine & "YYYY MM DD" & vbNewLine & "MM DD YYYY" & vbNewLine & "DD MM YYYY", vbCritical
        BDTextBox.Text = ""
        Cancel = True
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the code located? In other words - are you making sure it is still "connected to the textbox"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because like Userform Textbox, there is no `_Exit` Event for ActiveX Textbox embedded in the Excel Sheet. The equivalent event of `_Exit` is `_LostFocus`.

Try this.

```
Private Sub BDTextBox_LostFocus()
    If BDTextBox.Text <> "" Then
        If IsDate(BDTextBox.Text) Then
            BDTextBox.Text = Format(BDTextBox.Text, "yyyymmdd")
            FinalBusinessDate = BDTextBox.Text
        Else
            MsgBox "Please enter a valid date!" & vbNewLine & _
            "Date format could be one of the following" & _
            vbNewLine & "YYYY MM DD" & vbNewLine & _
            "MM DD YYYY" & vbNewLine & "DD MM YYYY", vbCritical
            BDTextBox.Text = ""

            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```